# Sum values in different categories by each financial asset

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE Movimentacao
( mydate DATE
, dividend_type VARCHAR(200)
, dividends DECIMAL(19, 2)
, ticker VARCHAR(300)
);
```

Inserting some data:

```
INSERT INTO Movimentacao VALUES
  ('2021-09-01', 'Dividend',  140, 'BBAS3 - BANCO DO BRASIL')
, ('2021-09-14', 'Dividend',  14,  'PETR4 - PETROBRAS SA')
, ('2021-09-14', 'Refund',    30,  'PETR4 - PETROBRAS SA')
, ('2021-09-04', 'JCP',       100, 'PETR4 - PETROBRAS SA')
, ('2021-09-03', 'Others',    11,  'VGIP12 - VALORA CRI ÍNDICE DE PREÇO FII')
, ('2021-09-21', 'Others',    22,  'IRDM11 - IRIDIUM FII')
, ('2021-10-07', 'Dividend',  100, 'BBAS3 - BANCO DO BRASIL')
;
```

My goal was to create the query below (working properly!) but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to build my code:

[image]

Any help to shrink/improve the code?

```
WITH AddColumns AS (
    SELECT
        substr(ticker, 1, INSTR(ticker, ' ')) AS ticker,

        CASE WHEN dividend_type = 'Dividend'
          THEN sum(dividends)
        END AS 'Dividend',
        
        CASE WHEN dividend_type = 'Refund' 
          THEN sum(dividends)
        END AS 'Refund',
        
        CASE WHEN dividend_type = 'JCP' 
          THEN sum(dividends)
        END AS 'JCP'
        
        FROM Movimentacao
        WHERE dividend_type IN ('Dividend', 'JCP', 'Refund') and mydate > '2021-01-01'
        GROUP BY ticker, dividend_type
), RemoveNullAndSum AS (
            SELECT ticker, sum(coalesce(Dividend,0)) as Dividend, 
                         sum(coalesce(JCP,0)) as JCP,
                         sum(coalesce(Refund,0)) as Refund
                FROM AddColumns
            GROUP BY ticker
), CreateTotalColumn AS (
    SELECT ticker, round(Dividend+Refund,2) as Dividend, 
                 round(JCP,2) as JCP,
                 round(Dividend+JCP+Refund,2) as Total FROM RemoveNullAndSum
)
    SELECT * FROM CreateTotalColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TOTAL', round(sum(Dividend),2), round(sum(JCP),2), round(sum(Total),2) 
    FROM CreateTotalColumn
```

Code link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5ac6537432906bd88ff3a85a6c3f0959

Comment: Why are you using SQLite? Would you consider switching to a more capable database if it made this query significantly simpler?

Comment: I'm running it on Django app @ localhost, that's why I'm using SQLite (personal application)! I was not assuming to migrate do Postgres. My question: would this migration (SQLite -> Postgres) make so much difference in this query?

Comment: I'm not hearing a "yes", so I'm not going to spend my time on writing an answer. I'll just leave two words as hints for you to research: "pivot" and "rollup".

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that I have changed from your code to make it more streamlined than your current version:

- inverted the position of `SUM` aggregate functions and `CASE` for filtering operation
- inside the `CASE`, since you're adding up refunds to every kind of "*dividend_type*", and dividend types are two, you can sum up your needed values by filtering out the non-interested dividend
- simplified the sum of all the different dividend types for the "*total*" field into a simple `SUM(dividends)`, which will get all and only the interested "*dividend_types*", given the filtering condition `WHERE dividend_type IN ('Dividend', 'JCP', 'Refund')`
- computed the rollup directly from the intermediate result using aggregation with no partitioning.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTR(ticker, 1, INSTR(ticker, ' '))     AS ticker,
           SUM(CASE WHEN dividend_type <> 'JCP'
                    THEN dividends ELSE 0 END)       AS Dividend,
           SUM(CASE WHEN dividend_type <> 'Dividend'
                    THEN dividends ELSE 0 END)       AS JCP,
           SUM(dividends)                            AS Total
    FROM Movimentacao
    WHERE dividend_type IN ('Dividend', 'JCP', 'Refund') AND mydate > '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY ticker
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', SUM(Dividend), SUM(JCP), SUM(Total) FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ZHMyNfjfwZZ5jSuEbgwpm/0).